# ASP.NET : How can i maintain objects between postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, postback

How can i maintain objects between ASP.NET page post backs ?

I have an ASP.NET web page.when i click one asp.net button, I will call my function (Save   ) which will create an object of my custom class (UserDetails class) and  save the details to DB.so this is a post back.After the post back again the same page will be displayed to user.At that time,I want to take the User object which i have created in the first function (Save ) . What is the best way to do this ? I know i can store this in a Session  and access it. But i want to know whethere there is any other better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you're looking for is some kind of databinding mechanism that binds the values of an object (you may load from the db if it already exists) to your asp.net webform.

Basically you'd have the following:

1. You display an empty webform with fields (i.e. textboxes) for the properties of your object
2. The user will fill the the form and press save
3. Then the postback will happen. On the PageLoad you can detect whether this is a postback with `Page.IsPostback` and if so, you create a new object and fill it with the values the user entered.
4. In the OnClick of your button, you call the appropriate BL method for storing it down to the DB

This would look like (I'm writing it out of my head without a compiler, so take care :) )

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{

    private Person myPersonObj;

    protected void Page_Load(...)
    {

        if(!Page.IsPostback)
        {
            //this is not a postback, so you may load an object based on an ID (i.e. in QueryString or create a new one
            myPersonObj = new Person();
        }
        else
        {
            //it is a postback, so unbind the values
            myPersonObj = new Person();
            Unbind(); //the myPersonObj will be filled, the values are managed by ASP.net in the ViewState
        }

    }

    //caution, overriding Page.DataBind()
    private override void DataBind()
    {
        textBoxFirstname.Text = myPersonObj.FirstName;
        ...

    }

    private void Unbind()
    {
        myPersonObj.FirstName = textBoxFirstname.Text;
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(...)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid)
        {
            Save();
        }
    }

    private void Save()
    {
         //ideal layering with Interfaces
         IPersonBL personBL = MyBLFactory.Get<IPersonBL>();
         personBL.SavePerson(myPersonObj); //call the BL for further validation and then persisting
    }
}
```

What I wanted to add yesterday, but forgot since I had to hurry:
You can as well store your objects in the ViewState or Session as others described, but I have experienced that it should be done as rare as possible due to the following "disadvantages" (from my point of view):

- Your objects need to be serializable
- Storing in the ViewState will drammatically increase the size of your page and thus slowing down the loading of your page. Note the ViewState is transferred to the client and back each time a "postback" occurs. If that's the only possibility and you're experiencing performance problems you may consider [trying this](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/02/howto-persist-viewstate-on-server-side/) (but this should be the exception!!)
- Storing Objects in your session may put the load on the server-side, consuming the memory there. You should be careful in storing objects in your session and possibly also care about destruction of those objects if you know you don't need them any more.

The advantage of the "databinding" approach I described is that you don't have these problems, with the "disadvantage" of having a new fresh object each time. You therefore have to take care of handling your object state, i.e. manually keeping id's through roundtrips etc..

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to store the object in the Cache using a unique key (e.g. "user" + id) and only store it's id in the current session or in the ViewState. During a postback, you can then retrieve the object from the cache.

With this approach you have several advantages:

- you have less data in your session or in the ViewState
- if a postback is made, you only have to access the DB if the object is no longer in the cache
- if no postback is made, the object will eventually be removed from the cache (freeing up memory)

Answer (score 3):

You can store the object in ViewState, this will be the page-specific storage. The object will then be serialized and injected into the page viewstate, which will make the page bigger.

By storing the object in session you keep the page smaller but consume server memory resources.

Alternatively, you can read the object from the database each time. This will have the advantage of displaying to the user exactly what was saved in the database.

Answer (score -1):

In UI Do this

```
    UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
    //do your stuff
    userDetail = UserBL.TransferUserData(userDetail);

    //do your stuff
```

In BL

```
public static UserDetail TransferUserData(UserDetail userDetail )
{
    // do your processing on userDetail
    return UserDAL.TransferUserData(userDetail);
}
```

In DAL

```
public static UserDetail TransferUserData(UserDetail userDetail)
{

    //do your processing of db
    return userDetail; 
}
```